# Use USART pin in UART mode

Tags: uart

I want to use a device who has an USART interface. But my microcontroller has only a UART communication.
Can I connect the UART_TX and UART_RX on USART_RX and USART_TX?

Thanks

Comment: Usually devices with a USART can be used synchronously or asynchronously, this detail will be in the manual for the device. If it can be used asynchronously then it will work as you intend.

Comment: Basically: if your device can be used in UART mode then it can be used in UART mode. You won't get a better answer until you ask a better question

Comment: A USART is by definition capable of asynchronous operation.  The distinction from a UART is that it also offers synchronous modes.  For contrast, a typical SPI or I2S engine can only operate in synchronous mode.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I want to use this component in USART:
http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/40001723D.pdf
With a micrcocontroller I want to used his UART to send it in USART pin to control the PWM.

Comment: @Tack the linked datasheet says "The EUSART,
also known as a Serial Communications Interface
(SCI), can be configured as a full-duplex asynchronous
system or half-duplex synchronous system" so you're fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can if you use only asynchronous communication (ie. without separate clock line).

By definition an UART is a special case of an USART.